# angular 2 http delete parameter url appended with [object%20Object]

Tags: json, angular, rest, http, http-status-code-404

I am using http.delete in angular 2 .This is my code

app.component.ts

```
deleteCourse(id: string)  {
       console.log(id);
       this.appService.deleteByID(id)

       .subscribe(x => {console.log(x); this.fetchCourseData(); }

        );
   }
```

app.service.ts

```
deleteByID(id: string): Observable<string> 

    let options1 = new RequestOptions();
    options1.headers = new Headers();
    options1.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/sample'+ '/' + id , options1)
     .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            return result; });
}
```

db.json

```
{
  "sample": [
    {

    {
      "courseTitle": "ggg",
      "courseDescription": "ggg",
      "courseCredit": "2",
      "id": 8
    },
    {
      "courseTitle": "ggg",
      "courseDescription": "ggg",
      "courseCredit": "1",
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "courseTitle": "add",
      "courseDescription": "asdas",
      "courseCredit": "2",
      "id": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

the url is passing as 
http://localhost:3000/sample/[object%20Object]

along with 404 error.How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that the console.log in deleteCourse prints out a string value. I managed to reproduce your issue was by passing an object as parameter to deleteCourse